# Interrupciones en Python

Tags: python

resumo mi problema con este pequeño código. Si cierro la ventana tkinter necesito que se detenga la ejecución de los hilos (loop1_10 y loop1_10b). Mi problema es que siguen funcionando hasta que terminan los bucles for. Hay alguna manera que se detengan si finalizo mi programa (cierre de la ventana principal)? Gracias!!!

Código:

```
import threading
import time
from tkinter import *

def loop1_10():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)

def loop1_10_b():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        time.sleep(2)
        print(i)


threading.Thread(target=loop1_10).start()
threading.Thread(target=loop1_10_b).start()

Ventana = Tk()

Ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: define una variable global que indique la condición de parar. La variable es puesta por la UI e interrogada por los threads.

Comment: Gracias por respuesta. Pero eso jústamente es lo que no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

Investigando encontré la solución. Hay que declar el hilo como "demonio". De ese modo se lo puede interrumpir.
El código quedaría así:

```
import threading

import time

from tkinter import *

def loop1_10():

    for i in range(1, 11):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)

def loop1_10_b():

    for i in range(1, 11):
        time.sleep(2)
        print(i)

Proceso1 = threading.Thread(target=loop1_10)

Proceso1.setDaemon(True)

Proceso1.start()

Proceso2 = threading.Thread(target=loop1_10_b)

Proceso2.setDaemon(True)


Proceso2.start()

MainWindow = Tk()

MainWindow.mainloop()
```